# How can I connect from Cloud Run Java application to a Cloud SQL database?

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql, vert.x, google-cloud-run

I have a Java/Vert.x application deployed as a Cloud Run container. It's running fine. I've tried to access my Cloud SQL MySQL instance to it, but to no avail. My application hangs as soon as I try to connect to the DB instance create a DataSource.

My Cloud Run container is associated with a service account with the *Cloud SQL Client* role.

I've followed the canonical GCP tutorial here:
https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-run
Obviously swapping in my specifics. Below is the offending code:

```
    private static final String PW = "mypassword";
    private static final String CONN_NAME = "/cloudsql/mydatabase-111222:us-west1:my-project";

    private DataSource pool;

    @Override
    public void init() throws Exception {
        LOGGER.info("MysqlRepo-init starting...");

        // The configuration object specifies behaviors for the connection pool.
        HikariConfig config = new HikariConfig();

        LOGGER.info("MysqlRepo-init 1");

        // Configure which instance and what database user to connect with.
        config.setJdbcUrl(String.format("jdbc:mysql:///%s", "mydb"));
        config.setUsername("root"); // e.g. "root", "postgres"
        config.setPassword(PW); // e.g. "my-password"

        // For Java users, the Cloud SQL JDBC Socket Factory can provide authenticated connections.
        // See https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-sql-jdbc-socket-factory for details.
        config.addDataSourceProperty("socketFactory", "com.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SocketFactory");
        config.addDataSourceProperty("cloudSqlInstance", CONN_NAME);
        config.addDataSourceProperty("useSSL", "false");

        LOGGER.info("MysqlRepo-init 2");
        // Initialize the connection pool using the configuration object.
        pool = new HikariDataSource(config);

        LOGGER.info("MysqlRepo-init 3");

        ResultSet rs = pool.getConnection().createStatement().executeQuery("SELECT COUNT(*) col FROM dual WHERE 1=1");

        LOGGER.info("MysqlRepo-init Results = " + rs.getFetchSize());

        LOGGER.info("...MysqlRepo-init done");
    }
```

My logs stop at "MysqlRepo-init 2" (beyond that, I get Vertx warnings that my main thread is blocked).

Any thoughts on what I might be missing?

Comment: Is y our database has a public IP? What is the error logs?

Comment: According to my Cloud SQL Overview dashboard, it has both a Public IP address and (of course) an Instance Connection Name (which is what I'm attempting to use to connect). So far, I'm not seeing any related error logs.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to have something to do with calling this code from a Vert.x verticle. When I called it directly from the application's main method, I was able to get useful log messages, which were complaining about the "/cloudsql/" portion of the connection name. That provided enough information to ultimately resolve ths issue.